# Which is correct; ‘proof for’ or ‘proof of’?

Tags: prepositions

Which is the correct preposition to follow ‘proof’ in this context:

> Most student enroll at unuversity with the aim of getting the degree required for a particular job. One good proof *for/ of* this is a recent survey conducted in some Egyptian universities......

Should I write ‘for’ or ‘of’?

Comment: Idiomatically, ***of*** is very much [the preferred preposition](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+proof+for+this%2Cthe+proof+of+this&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20proof%20for%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20proof%20of%20this%3B%2Cc0) here, as shown by that NGram. But it's really no more than a "conventionally established" usage - there's no particular reason (logical or semantic) for ***proof of*** being the dominant form.

Comment: The (low) usage of "proof for" may be coming from different usage patterns. For example (in maths) "one method of proof *for* this class of problems is to ..." is normal, but "one method of proof *of* this class of problems ..." is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

Either are acceptable depending on how one uses them

> Proof Of Concept

is an established term in business and elsewhere to show evidence that something can be done.

It is never

> Proof **for** Concept

Consider

> The proof **for** the viability of our proposal was demonstrated by the Proof **of** Concept.